# Categorizing data using text processing

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn, nltk

I have a dataset where I need to categorize data using there units, like

```
UNITS        PRICE
pieces       100
piece        70
peice        50
1 pc         50
pics         60
single piece 50
```

Assumption: pieces and piece may be considered as same

Here all the units must point to the same root word (piece). I did apply `stemming` and `lemmatization` from the `nltk` library in python, but it did not give the desired result.

Applying stemming to some examples,

```
from nltk.stem import PorterStemmer
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
stemmer= PorterStemmer()
input_str=['pieces', 'piece', 'peice', '1 pc', 'pics', 'single Peice']
for word in input_str:
    print(stemmer.stem(word), end=' ')
```

The output it gave is,

```
piec piec peic 1 pc pic singl peic
```

Is there any way to consider approximately similar looking words as same ?

I don't know how should I proceed to the problem. Can anyone please suggest something ?

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned stemming or lemmatization does not correct the spelling.

There are quite few options to auto correct the spelling but be aware that those can fail at some instances. May be a manual intervention would be required if you need Fool proof correction.

1. [pySpellChecker](https://pypi.org/project/pyspellchecker/)
2. [autocorrect](https://github.com/phatpiglet/autocorrect/tree/master/autocorrect)

Sometimes, you may need to correct the misplaced spaces, in such situation you could use [word segment](https://pypi.org/project/wordsegment/).